# Вывод разных страниц на основе параметров URL

Tags: php, url

Вот мой код:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/okt/') {
    $page = 'home';
} else {
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 5);

    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9,\.\/+]{3,20}$/', $page)){
        exit('error url');
    }
}



if (file_exists('okt/all/'.$page.'.php')) include 'okt/all/'.$page.'.php'; 
elseif ( file_exists('okt/auth/'.$page.'.php')) include 'okt/auth/'.$page.'.php'; 
elseif ( file_exists('okt/guest/'.$page.'.php')) include 'okt/guest/'.$page.'.php';
else exit('Страница не найдена');?>
```

У меня есть папка `all`, в которой лежит файл `info.php`. Предполагается, что при вводе в адресную строку после `http://127.0.0.1/okt/` слова `info` должен открыться файл `info.php` из папки `all`. Но этого не происходит: постоянно срабатывает условие `else` и я получаю `СТРАНИЦА НЕ НАЙДЕНА`. Помогите, уже замучился искать ошибку.

Comment: Для начала посмотрите что выводит переменная `$page` на странице http://127.0.0.1/okt/info

Comment: К тому же в функцию `file_exists()` нужно передавать абсолютный путь до файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вне зависимости от того, что у вас в `.htaccess` файле (что само по себе важно). Укажите полный путь до файла или используйте переменную `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, к примеру:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/okt/all/'.$page.'.php'
```

При таком варианте все должно работать корректно.

Comment: В .htaccess у меня: AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /okt/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

Comment: Пожалуйста скажите куда конкретно я должен вставить $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/okt/all/'.$page.'.php' я не особо понял где его использовать

Comment: Измените последние 4 строки вашего кода: `'okt/` на `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/okt/`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло! А почему именно так решаеться вопрос? Я прохожу уроки по ютюбу у автора работает без $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: Видимо разница все-таки есть, может в настройках сервера или дело в именах папок. Можете попробовать заменить `'okt/all/'.$page.'.php';`  на `'all/'.$page.'.php'; `. Такой вариант тоже должен сработать, но все-таки надежнее указывать полный путь с использованием или без использования `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. По идее если у вас директория на сервере okt/ имеется то, сервер осуществляет сначала переход в нее, а вот потом уже ищет проверяемый файл `'okt/all/'.$page.'.php'`, т.е. конечный путь будет `'okt/okt/all/'.$page.'.php'` от корня сайта (а его таки там нет).